Is 163°F for my new fluorescent ballast too hot?
My neighbor who is a master electrician recently installed a new ballast for my fluorescent light fixture. On a whim, I just decided to inspect the work when I felt the light cover was a little warm. I used my infrared temp gun to take some readings. I measured the ballast and it was 163°F. Is this normal?

F or C? that will matter

Kelvin? pretty cold...

Sorry, Fahrenheit.

What's the wattage rating of the ballast and how many tubes of what wattage is it driving?

I’m unsure of the wattage on the ballast, but the product info is, GE Ultramax P series GE432MAXP-N-DIY. It’s running 4, 4 foot tubes that are 32 watts each.

Obviously, the ballast is wasting significant energy as heat, though it might be within safe temperature. Next time you need to fix that, replace with an efficient LED that does not reuse the existing ballast. My experience has been that LED replacements last far longer than the fluorescent lamp, too.

I may just do it anyways and see about returning the ballast if they’ll take it back.
